# Dump Postgres database as XML or JSON file from Docker Container

Tags: postgresql, docker

I regularly backup my Postgres database, which is running in a Docker container, with the following command:

```
docker exec -t database pg_dumpall -c -U postgres > dump.sql
```

For a new process, I need the database dump either as an XML or JSON file. How can I perform the database dump by creating an XML or JSON file instead of an SQL file?

Comment: Create a script that constructs the XML of JSON in the required format.

Comment: So, there is no integrated Postgres feature which let me dump the database in the required format?

Comment: No. And XML just tells you that it is XML, not about the format. How should a database dump in XML look like? How would you define the constraints, datatypes, etc. in XML format? Same thing in JSON.